# .netCore identityServerJwt, login success, cookies set, but no authentication. User.Identity.Name null and all the fileds are nulls or empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, identity

Can't get any detail about the user after he logged in although client side have the AspNetCore.Identity.Application token. Seem like he isn't authenticated although the cookies are set correctly. I searched a lot of question and didn't manage to solve it yet.

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        }
        /*options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true*/)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();



        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

            //options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            //options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            //options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });


        //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => {
        //    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        //});
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa => {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

IdentityHostingStartup.cs:

```
      public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
        });
    }
}
```

Relavant controller:

```
private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signManager; //User
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signManager) {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signManager = signManager;
    }

    // GET: AccountController
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: AccountController/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id) {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: AccountController/Create
    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: AccountController/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Create([FromBody] RegistrtionData registrtionData) {

        if (registrtionData != null) {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = registrtionData.name, Email = registrtionData.email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registrtionData.password);

            return Json(result);
        }
        return Json("null data");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginData loginData) {

        if (loginData != null) {
            var result = await _signManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginData.userName,
               loginData.password, true, false);
            return Ok("login result" + result);             
        }
        return Ok("got null data as login data");
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Logout() {
        try {
            await _signManager.SignOutAsync();
            return Json(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Json(false);
        }
    }
```

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
        //public string password { get; set; }
        //public string name { get; set; }
        //public string familyName { get; set; }
        //public int age { get; set; }


}
```

Client Side:

```
nSubmit(formData: NgForm) {
this.serverService.login(formData.form.value).subscribe(result => {
  if (result.succeeded) {
    this.loginMeassage = ''
    this.router.navigate(['/heroScreen'])
  }
  else {
    this.loginMeassage = 'ERROR, password or username incorrect!!'
  }

}, error => console.error('error', error));
```

Network request, response cookie (jwt) ontop, and the req cookie down (it's suppose to change every communication??):
[image: Login request]

User after more then 1 request:
[image: User varaible]

Comment: I don't see where you have set the endpoint to require authentication. This may explain why the jwt token details are not populated.

Comment: hi, i'm not sure what u mean by setting the endpoint to require the authentication, it's seem that the client side getting the cookies automaticlly. 
I edited the post and added more data.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so after wasting probably 15 hours on this.. 
Turns out u need to set DefaultAuthenticateScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme. 
So instead of:

```
 services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Do this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        }).AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Also, possible unrelated walkaround (but kinda ugly):

```
var cookie = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme); 
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(cookie.Principal);
```

hope it's will help somebody someday.

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks from an internet stranger two years later.